# prisma query for json type using path and equals with variables instead of string

Tags: node.js, dynamic, prisma

I have been trying to use prisma findMany where condition for string match in json.
Clm Phone_Numbers in prisma model Test is of Json type.

Following is my code:
`var findthis = "19999999999"`
`var findMatch = await prisma.Test.findMany({`
`where:{`
`OR: [`
 `{ Phone_Numbers: { path: ["primaryPhone"], equals: findthis } },`
`{ Phone_Numbers: { path: ['SecondaryPhone'], equals: findthis } }`
`]`
`}, select:{ id:true } })`

The above query works if instead of findthis in equals I use "19999999999" directly. Is there a way where i can use a variable to get the match?